# Would it be feasible to use the water vapor produced from hydrogen internal combustion engines to power a steam generator in a car?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, car, power-generation

In a standard internal combustion engine, exhaust temperatures typically approach 400-500 degrees Celsius for standard applications. If we consider that the primary exhaust gas of hydrogen engines is water vapor (with some NOx as well, but engines that run higher compression ratios have less NOx in them), is it then possible to use small steam turbines to generate electricity for a potential hybrid power train? The potential applications associated with this technology would be tremendous for specifically the world of motorsports, allowing us to substantially increase engine efficiency, especially at higher RPMs because of the increased exhaust temperature.

Comment: ask about exhaust back pressure effect on engine efficiency at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Temperature limit on a 6 cylinder turbo-charged diesel, about 6L, was about 700 degrees C - know this because the onboard computer would display the temperature while it was working hard and I wanted to see if it would shut the engine down (as per the manual)... Never hit the limit - got close but never scored. So, what is this mythical increased temperature you mention? Any references to back this up?

Comment: It's just the same as an ordinary turbocharger. There are some differences in that the molecular wt of water vapor is much lower than carbon dioxide. That changes the exhaust velocities achievable at any given temperature, and thus the optimal turbo geometry will be slightly different than a hydrocarbon turbo. Note also the density of vapor is less than half that of carbon dioxide, so the exhaust plumbing at a given power has to be larger. So you want a bit more backpressure with hydrogen in order to get the stuff out the valves.

Comment: If you supply excess hydrogen, you have an exhaust component that has a molecular weight of 2. That stuff is really fast and can significantly effect the turbo's geometry. But getting it past the valves is a challenge for large displacements. Rockets run rich in hydrogen in order to improve specific impulse.

Comment: Quibble - A steam generator makes steam. A steam turbine runs on steam.